# Adding Objects to an ArrayList without error

Tags: java

I am just trying to add some objects to an ArrayList in eclipse, but i keept getting an error (Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameterList) under the 'persons.add(one);'. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
package thequestion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person>{

   @Override
   public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
       return 0;
   }

   Person one = new Person("Kevin", "Gresmer");
   List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

   persons.add(one);

   public void sortByLastName(List people) {
       Comparator comp = new PersonComparator();
       Collections.sort(people, comp);
   }
}


public class Person {
    private String firstName = null;
    private String lastName = null;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `persons.add(one);` statement isn't within a method. Only *declarations* can be directly within a class.

Comment: When do you think `persons.add(one);` should be invoked?

Comment: (And what is the point of `persons` at all here?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only initialize the instance variables in class and outside the methods. 
You initialized persons. Then to apply methods, you need to put that line into some methods. So, may be you can update your Sort Method or create new one and make reference to that method from your sort method.

- The first option as explained in the above comment.

  class PersonComparator implements Comparator{

  ```
     @Override
     public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
         return 0;
     }

     Person one = new Person("Kevin", "Gresmer");
     List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

     private void addPersons(){
       persons.add(one);
     }
                    //persons.add(one);

     public void sortByLastName(List people) {
         addPersons();
         Comparator comp = new PersonComparator();
         Collections.sort(people, comp);
     }
  }
  ```

The point is we cannot write anything except the Instance variables. We have to cover them with methods. I hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The line `persons.add(one)` is a statement, and you can't have a statement outside a block of code (method, constructor, etc.). Also, your `Comparator` should contain code related to the comparison you are doing. I don't think it's the right place to store a list or implement the `sortByLastName()` method.

Answer (score 0):

put below under `sortByLastName` method. Currently below code snippet not lying under any method.

```
    persons.add(one);
```

Correct code should be

```
public void sortByLastName(List people) {

       persons.add(one);
       Comparator comp = new PersonComparator();
       Collections.sort(persons , comp);
   }
```

**please note :-** But my answer is in terms of compilation error. Ideally comparator should have code only related to comparison. Nothing else.

Comment: Don't think it should go there =). He is lacking a constructor - give him one

Comment: I don't think that this code should be part of `PersonComparator` class at all.

Comment: @Pshemo you are correct. But my answer is in terms of compilation error

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you cannot do `persons.add(...)` in the middle of the class declaration.

You should certainly add `one` and `persons` in a `main` in the class `Person`, and keep your `Comparator` class clean with only the logic of comparison. The `main` will allow you to test your code.
The same idea for the `sortByLastName(...)` you can declare it as `static` in `Person` class. 
Then you can test with the main, e.g.

```
// In class `Person`
public static void main(String[] args) {
   List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
   Person one = new Person("Kevin", "Gresmer");
   persons.add(one);
   Person two = new Person("Elvis", "Presley");
   persons.add(two);
   System.out.println(sortByLastName(persons));
}
```

Note for the above to provide a sensible output, you need to add a `toString()` method to the `Person` class.